# Hiding folder from URL / Active menu item / Error handler

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, yii

I wanted to ask for your help on following questions:

1) In my project I use CMS Yupe (based on Yii Framework) and their standard directory structure (index.php is located in the 'public' directory, and not at the root of the project). And I have a question: how to remove from the address bar "public" directory: mysite.com/public/site/news ---> mysite.com/site/news
I.e. what actions need to be taken in a way that will never be displayed /public/?

So, my directories structure like this:

public

---index.php

protected

vendor

2) In the front-end part of the project I used usual menu & I want to highlight active items of it. First, the choice fell on jQuery, but the decision turned out to be very bad, because of the fact that the class="active" tag  exhibited only the current (coinciding in URL) address of the page (for example, mysite.com/news ), but if it has the same (active) item has parameters (mysite.com/news/some-news), a light is lost, and animation work out there with procrastination. As a way out - JS developers to deal with such cases on the server. I wanted to ask you: HOW?))

3) How and where to best handle this type of error: If the reference attribute href="#" (or any other, which means that the material is not currently ready for display), then going anywhere in the site at this URL output CHttpError (a code, by the way, here's advise for such a message?) "Materials prepared for publication ..."

Thank you very much in advance for your help & I'm sorry for my bad English :)